# Analytic functions where all derivatives vanish at infinity and which are bounded

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-operators

Let $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ denote the analytic functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I wonder whether there a functions $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ with $f \neq 0$, such that there is a constant $C$, with $$\left| \frac{d^kf(x)}{dx^k} \right | \leq C$$ for all $k \geq 0$, and $\frac{d^kf(x)}{dx^k}$ vanish both at $- \infty$ and $\infty$ for all $k \geq 0$.

Comment: What about $(\sin x)/x$?

Comment: also, technically, since you didn't specify non-trivial, I guess $f\equiv 0$ is another exampl.

Comment: @Willie Wong Thanks for pointing it out, I amended it.

Comment: @RichardStanley It seems $sin(x)/x$ is doing the job. However, is there an easy proof for it?

Comment: @tobias It's easy to see that the derivatives of $(\sin x)/x$ vanish at $\pm\infty$, but I don't see an easy way to show that they are uniformly bounded.

Comment: @tobias: for a rescaled sinc function you can also get the proof using my answer. the fact that its Fourier transform is the rectangle function and not smooth is inconsequential: the Fourier transform of all its derivatives are bounded with compact support, so the decay at infinity can be also gotten via Riemann-Lebesgue.

Answer (score 18):

Yes.

Let $\phi$ be any smooth function with compact support on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Set $f$ to be the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi$.

Since $\phi$ is in Schwartz class, so is $f$, and all of its derivatives decay to zero as one approach $\pm\infty$.

You can estimate

$$ |f^{(k)}(x) | \lesssim \| |\xi|^k \phi(\xi) \|_{L^1} \leq 2 \|\phi\|_{L^\infty} =: C$$

$f$ is analytic by Paley-Wiener.

Comment: Why do you specify “inverse” Fourier transform and not simply the Fourier transform? For thepurposes of question it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Because for my own sanity I like to keep track of which functions are on the frequency domain and which are on the time domain. (Force of habit.)